# Setting up CouchDB 2.2 on windws10

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have isntalled CouchDB 2.2 on my computer over Windows10.
All the CouchDB configuration I have is the default after the installion.
I can access to Futon doing

> localhost:5984/_utils

or

> 127.0.0.1:5984/_utils

But the datebase is not accesible outsite from my machine, lets say from a tablet .
I have been reading I have to change the `httpd` setting field to

> 0.0.0.0

but is not accesible outsite either . All devices are in the same net.

This is the configuration I have:[image]
[image]

What I have to do in order to expose CouchDb dateBase outsite from my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `chttpd` is the interface to access the Cluster node. The `httpd` section relate to the node interface.

So in order to have your node accessible from the outside, you need to change the `bind_address` of the `httpd` section to:

> 0.0.0.0

So if you go on another device and enter the remote ip of your server, you should be able to access your node interface.

If you can't still access, you want want to check your firewalls or the CORS settings in Fauxton.

Comment: with remote ip of your server , do you mean my computer IPv4 ?

Comment: Well it depends, first, you can use another device in your local network and see if it works by accessing your local ipv4 address. Then, if you don't have a public ip that points to your computer, you need to portforward your external ip to your pc ip.

Comment: With the ipv4 does not work,About  Portforwarding , could please provide me a web site about how to do it , thanks

Comment: Here's a link: https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/ You can always reach me on the CouchDB slack. It would be easier to help you even if it's kind out of the scope of the question